# Integration test and unit test (WEB API mvc 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, integration-testing, asp.net-web-api

how does the integration test and unit test relevant in doing testing on APIController? and how can i mock the repository while creating the webrequest in  the integration test so it does not make an actual query to the database?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Self Hosting](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-Self-Host-30abca12) functionality to start up the controllers and use the `OpenAsync().ContinueWith(t => { /* ... */ })` function to run your tests. You'll want to override the `Configuration.DependencyResolver` and override the `IHttpControllerActivator` so that you can specify your own mock implementation (e.g. you can use Ninject to retrieve the specific controller already bound up with a mock implementation).

Comment: Find a full example here: http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/07/should-i-unit-or-integration-test-my.html

Comment: @JefClaes Your article is most useful!  With examples and all, showing how to do an entire end-to-end test using MVC Web API without firing up a web server.  Very nice.

Comment: Remark: this is supported only on `ApiController` (WebApi), not `Controller` (of MVC which is also a mentioned in a tag to this question).