# What should a controller integration test assert

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, asp.net-web-api2

Doing an integration test on a web api endpoint what should I put my focus on to assert?

My endpoint is also doing a call to a domain service.

Should I mock that service? With the current code that is not possible, because I would need to instantiate the controller to pass the mock service.

Am I interested in the service return value? actually not.
I am only interested wether the endpoint was succesfully triggered but then I should isolate the service call I guess.

Any advice is welcome :-)

**TEST**

```
[TestClass]
public class SchoolyearControllerTests
{
    private TestServer _server;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void FixtureInit()
    {
        _server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void FixtureDispose()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Get()
    {
        var response = _server.HttpClient.GetAsync(_server.BaseAddress + "/api/schoolyears").Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<SchoolyearDTO>>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

**Action to test**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var schoolyears = await service.GetSchoolyears();
    return Ok(schoolyears);
}
```

Comment: Again... Why 2 close votes?

Answer (score 4):

The trouble with doing an integration test on a web service is that it doesn't tell you very much about the problem - or even if there actually is one, and if there is, it doesn't tell you where the issue lies. It will either succeed or fail.  So in that respect did you get a 200 response code or a 500 response code... but did it fail because:

- The server was unreachable
- The web service isn't started, or failed when trying to start
- A firewall is blocking the network
- A database record wasn't found
- There's a database schema problem and entity framework didn't start 
  properly.

It could literally be anything - and result might be different on your dev machine than in production - so what does it really tell you about your application?

What makes for robust software is to test that your product is able to handle any of these situations correctly, gracefully and robustly.

I write my controller actions like this:

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var person = _personRepository.GetById(id);
            var dto = Mapper.Map<PersonDto>(person);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<PersonDto>(HttpStatusCode.OK, dto);
            return response;
        }
        catch (TextFileDataSourceException ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            return response;
        }
        catch (DataResourceNotFoundException ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            return response;
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

A try block gets the data, makes a dto and returns the data with a 200 code. There are several error conditions handled here, but none indicate a problem with my web service itself and some (404 error) don't even indicate an issue with the application - I EXPECT a NotFoundException and a 404 if my application can't find a record - if this happens my application WORKS in this scenario.

So if any of these error conditions occur, its not because there's a problem with the web service, and not necessarily a problem with the app.  But I can test that my web service is returning the correct response for any of these expected conditions.

The tests for this controller action looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanGetPerson()
    {
        #region Arrange
        var person = new Person
            {
                Id = 1,
                FamilyName = "Rooney",
                GivenName = "Wayne",
                MiddleNames = "Mark",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1985, 10, 24),
                DateOfDeath = null,
                PlaceOfBirth = "Liverpool",
                Height = 1.76m,
                TwitterId = "@WayneRooney"
            };

        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>(); 

        var mockPersonRepository = new Mock<IPersonRepository>();
        mockPersonRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(1)).Returns(person);

        var controller = new PersonController(mockPersonRepository.Object);

        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "1");
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration(new HttpRouteCollection());
        #endregion

        #region act
        HttpResponseMessage result = controller.Get(1);
        #endregion

        #region assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
        #endregion
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanHandlePersonNotExists()
    {
        #region Arrange
        var mockPersonRepository = new Mock<IPersonRepository>();
        mockPersonRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(1)).Throws<DataResourceNotFoundException>();

        var controller = new PersonController(mockPersonRepository.Object)
            {
                Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "1"),
                Configuration = new HttpConfiguration(new HttpRouteCollection())
            };

        #endregion

        #region Act
        HttpResponseMessage result = controller.Get(1);
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, result.StatusCode);
        #endregion
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanHandleServerError()
    {
        #region Arrange
        var mockPersonRepository = new Mock<IPersonRepository>();
        mockPersonRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(1)).Throws<Exception>();

        var controller = new PersonController(mockPersonRepository.Object);
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "1");
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration(new HttpRouteCollection());
        #endregion

        #region Act
        HttpResponseMessage result = controller.Get(1);
        #endregion

        #region Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result.StatusCode);
        #endregion
    }
```

Note that I'm introducing a mock respository and having my mock repository trigger the expected exceptions for 404 and server error and ensuring that the web service handles it correctly.

What this tells me is that my web service handling expected and exceptional situations as it should and returning the appropriate codes: 200/404/500.

Although some are error states and some are success states, none of these outcomes indicate a problem with my web service - it is behaving exactly as it should, and that's what I want to test.

An 'across the network' integration test on a web service tells you nothing about the robustness or correctness of your application - or even if its returning the correct data or response-code.

Don't try to re-test WebAPI... Microsoft wrote a massive suite of tests for it already - hundreds of test-fixture classes, thousands of test methods:

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Http.Test/Controllers/ApiControllerTest.cs

Assume that WebAPI works as it should and doesn't require you to test it again.  Focus on testing your application code and make sure success and error conditions are handled gracefully by your web service.

If you want to check your web service is connected and available on the network - open a browser and test it manually; there's no need to automate this; the result will vary between environments and according to external conditions.

Test each layer of your application the same way, mock out the layer above and test that the current layer handles every possible outcome from the layer above.

Your client application for your service should do the same thing: Mock the web service, and pretend that it gave a 404 - and check that it handles this as it should.

Comment: What you did is a unit test. But I want to do integration testing see here: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/12/owin-memory-integration-testing/ I want to know when I enter "api/schoolyears" in the url bar (do not need a browser for this) that my Get method is triggered. This has nothing to do with your unit test expectations. Yes you are right in my quick hacked Get Method I always get Code 200. I catch only those exceptions which I expect. When someone forgot to plugin the database I can log this but I do not react on it with a pink user dialog. I just let it crash.

Comment: You wrote lots now and all is correct for unit testing. But Its sadly not what I expected or helps me in my special case, see my question. Maybe my method to test is too simple that it really shows why an integration test here makes sense. More infrastructure stuff should be involved like setting headers, adding query parameters, someone removes a Http verb Attribute - is your endpoint still triggered? -

Comment: Well I was questioning whether you actually need an integration test, and what value you get from this... From your comment it sounds like you want to test that the correct route is triggered based on a certain HTTP Verb or QueryString - this is a different problem and doesn't require any form of integration: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/testing-routes-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Well there are many things I want to have in an integration test. (very generally spoken...) Funny is that you post also a link from strathweb which is actually a follower of integration tests on web api but you aren`t. Sometimes reasons are just opinions. Can you tell me when YOU would do an integration test? Even when I have 5 delegating handlers before my controller action is executed those I could also unit test...

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927587/integration-test-and-unit-test-web-api-mvc-4 very nice attached sample link with exactly the answer I needed how to mock the service! I will NOT vote for closing this duplicate thread so you get the points and my upvote to 3 :-)